# How to add a solid black border around a layer when it is under a Hue/Saturation Layer in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, black, stroke

I have a Layer which i have adjusted Hue/Saturation with a Hue Saturation Layer in CS 5.1 . I want a solid black border around it. Now when i go to apply stroke to it in blending options, the stroke gets Hue corrected too and its not coming as a solid black border. I know that one work around is to create separate black border layers and keep on top of the hue saturated layers. Is there a better way ? I have added images for clarity.

These squares are all separate layers.

[image: screenshot]

I need to have a solid black border around each of these boxes. But currently the layers are stacked like this.

[image: shot 2]

So if try to use stroke around it, i get something like this instead of a solid black border.

[image: shot 3]

Is there a way to get a solid black border around these tiles ?

Comment: Aside from the actual question. It looks like you have used a blend mode to show the image in your colored boxes only. That's not very good practice. Something like Layer mask or clipping mask would be better for future editing.

Comment: There are a couple ways to handle this with a new layer. Are you completely opposed to a new layer? If so, I think the only option is to mask the Hue/Saturation adjustment layer so it doesn't effect the strokes.

Comment: What is your Hue mask doing, it looks like an empty layer to me??

Comment: @Ryan That's an Adjustment layer. `Layer > New adjustment layer > ...` Or the yin yang'ish icon at the bottom of layer panel.

Comment: @Joonas I havent worked with Clipping Masks that much. Just saw a tutorial. Seems to be easy . I will implement it. But i do want the picture to blend in with the colors. So i have to use blending even after i use a clipping mask right ?

Comment: @Scott I am fine with a new layer too. But just that i have like 12 of these boxes each with different dimensions. Is there a way in which i can just apply stroke and make it a new layer by itself ?

Comment: @Ryan The Hue Mask serves as an adjustment to all the layers below it. You could check the change from the thumbnail in the layers window to the one in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments....

Command/Ctrl-Shift-Click each layer thumbnail for the shapes (Layer 2, Layer, 3, layer 4 copy 2, etc.)

This will load each layers transparency as a selection. The Shift key will add to the current selection. So, with each Command/Ctrl-Shift-Click on a layer thumbnail, you should see the current selection grow by that layer's shape.

Do this for all the layers containing the shapes.

Now, New layer above the Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer.

Fill the selection with a color (any color)

Set the Fill to 0% on the Layers Panel.

Choose Layer > Layer Style > Stroke

Play with the stroke settings to get what you want.

That should do it if I understand what you're after.

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Just add an outer glow around it, change the glow's blend-mode type to "normal" so that you can use solid colors, select black, and set the opacity to 100% so that it's a truly "solid" color, then drag the "spread" all the way up and drag the "size" very very low so that it isn't a glow at all but instead just a strong solid black border of any thickness you want.

To have the border go on the inside if you needed just use an inner-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Group both the layer and adjustment layer into a layer group (or smart object if you prefer) and apply the stroke effect to that.